# Using thmbox's title with lyx

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

Hello
I'm trying to create my own layout

I'm using thmbox package for theorems, and I want to use the title feature.
I'm using LyX  as my editor, and I've created a layout file defining several styles using newboxtheorem-s. is there any way to make lyx understand that the layout takes a parameter and create a wysiwyg environment for it?
Thanks.

Comment: If you show the layout file you've created, chances will increase that someone knowledgeable in LyX takes a closer look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem long ago,
Just needed to add:

OptionalArgs 1

to the Style Theorem scope.